# sed fails to remove newline character

Tags: sed, newlines

I've been using `sed` for quite some time but here is a quirk I came around with, which I am not able to resolve.

Let me explain my problem with the actual case.

---

**Scene#1**

```
printf "ls" | xclip -selection clipboard
echo "ls" | xclip -selection clipboard
```

In the first command, I pipe `printf` output to `xclip` so that it gets copied to the clipboard. Now, `printf`, unlike `echo` does not insert a new line at the end by default. So, if I paste this content into terminal, the `ls` command that is copied does not automatically run.

In the second, there is a new line at the end, so pasting the clipboard content also results in the running of the command in the clipboard.

This is undesirable for me. So, I wanted to remove the newline using `sed`, but it failed, as explained in the scene below.

**Scene#2**

```
echo "ls" | sed -r 's/\n//g' | xclip -selection clipboard
```

The content in the clipboard still contains new-line. When I paste it into terminal, the command automatically runs.

I also tried removing carriage return character `\r`. But nada. It seems I am missing something very crucial/basic here.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`sed` delimits on `\n`ewlines - they are always removed on input and reinserted on output. There is *never* a `\n`ewline character in a `sed` pattern space which did not occur as a result of an edit you have made.
*Note: with the exception of GNU `sed`'s `-z` mode...*

Just use `tr`:

```
echo ls | tr -d \\n | xclip -selection clipboard
```

Or, better yet, forget `sed` altogether:

```
printf ls | xclip -selection clipboard
```

Comment: This will remove **all** newlines, often not desirable in the `generate-text | xclip` case. [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/543991/143394) only removes the last newline.

Comment: Really? What about `sed -e ':lbl N; s/\n//; t lbl'` ?

Answer (score 11):

You can replace newlines in sed by passing it the **-z** option.

```
sed -z 's/\n/ /g'
```

Sed man page:

> **-z, --null-data** separate lines by NUL characters

Comment: This will remove **all** newlines, which is generally not be desired in the `| xclip` case.

Answer (score 9):

Many text processing tools, including sed, operate on the content of the line, excluding the newline character. The first thing sed does when processing a line is to strip off the newline at the end, then it executes the commands in the script, and it adds a final newline when printing out. So you won't be able to remove the newline with sed.

To remove all the newlines, you can use `tr` instead:

```
echo "ls" | tr -d '\n' | xclip
```

---

Answer (score 3):

To remove **only the last newline**, pipe through:

```
sed -z '$ s/\n$//'
```

`sed` won't add a `\0` to then end of the stream if the delimiter is set to `NUL` via `-z`, whereas to create a POSIX text file (defined to end in a `\n`), it will always output a final `\n` without `-z`.

Eg:

```
$ { echo foo; echo bar; } | sed -z '$ s/\n$//'; echo tender
foo
bartender
```

And to prove no `NUL` added:

```
$ { echo foo; echo bar; } | sed -z '$ s/\n$//' | xxd
00000000: 666f 6f0a 6261 72                        foo.bar
```

---

To **remove multiple trailing newlines**, pipe through:

```
sed -Ez '$ s/\n+$//'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are just putting commands in the clipboard

```
echo -n "ls " | xclip -selection clipboard
```

If you additionally need to make more complex transformations,

```
echo "ls  " | perl -pe 's/\n//' | xclip -selection clipboard
```

Comment: Hmm. Smooth solution. I guess it is perhaps time to move on to perl or python for regex.

Comment: @shivams - `perl` and `python` are both *much slower* than `sed` can be when used correctly. Learning to use it correctly is the key, though.

Comment: @mikeserv - I agree; special for oneliner sed is wonderful. If the transformations are going to become more complex, then I prefer perl/python/gawk.

Comment: @JJoa: Your preference is your own, but `sed` can do far more than handle just your one-liners, and it can likely do so faster than any of those other tools you mention.

Comment: @mikeserv - once again, I agree with you. Some year ago I had a translation system EN-PT written in sed (20000 s/.../.../), generated by sed! And it worked! Later it became Perl, to have arrays, hashes, functions, packages and CPAN.