# Changing linefeed by another character in bash

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a file like this one with ID over several lines but I need all records to be on the same line:

```
8600
22007
93509
9984
22146
```

to `8600,22007,93509,9984,22146`

Even if I can do it in vi with sed `1,$ s/\n/,/g`, I need to do it automatically with bash.

I tried `sed -i 's/\n/,/g' filename` with no luck.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 6):

with single `paste` command:

```
paste -d, -s infile
```

`-s` makes the command to print lines in **s**erial with `-d,` on comma separated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tr`

```
tr '\n' ,
```

This will change *every* instance of `\n` to a comma, so you'll need to fix up the last one. Here's an example

```
cat >file.txt <<x
8600
22007
93509
9984
22146
x

tr '\n' , <file.txt
8600,22007,93509,9984,22146,        # and the shell prompt follows immediately

tr '\n' , <file.txt | sed 's/,$/\n/'
8600,22007,93509,9984,22146         # line is ended with newline
```

Note that this use of `sed` is not defined by POSIX, which expects all lines to be terminated with newline. You can fix this by inserting `awk 1` into the pipeline, because `awk` is explicitly defined by POSIX to add a trailing newline to the final line if one is missing:

```
tr '\n' , <file.txt | awk 1 | sed 's/,$//'
8600,22007,93509,9984,22146         # line is ended with newline
```

For a quick fix, this would be acceptable (although the `paste` solution offered elsewhere is superior). However, `tr | awk | sed` is an ugly combination that should be revisited in production code. So we can end up with this:

```
awk 'NR>1 {printf ","}; {printf "%s", $0}; END {printf "\n"}' file.txt
```

Comment: Great, I've also tried tr but in the wrong way as I was doing a cat which read the file line by line.

Comment: Note that that `sed 's/,$/\n/'` is not POSIX, first because the behaviour is unspecified if the input doesn't end in a newline character (some `sed`s will ignore that unterminated line), and also because of that `\n` (POSIXly, you'd use backslash followed by a newline character). Using `paste -sd,` is much better here.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `sed` and assuming there's no `POSIXLY_CORRECT` variable in the environment or if there is, that the input has at least two lines:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g' input.txt
```

[we can't replace newline](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/180902/270935). But we can do by appending all line as above.....

Answer (score 0):

Use `tr`:

```
$ <input.txt tr "\n" ","
8600,22007,93509,9984,22146,
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in pure Bash, you can:

```
ar=( $(<filename) )
( IFS=, echo "${ar[*]}" > filename )
```

This makes an array, `ar`, with the whitespace-separated words of `filename` as elements, and then prints it out with commas between the items. These are all built-in Bash features.

If you have strange characters (e.g. `*`) in your data lines, this will misbehave, but for your data it works.

You could also use

```
tmp=$(printf '%s,' $(<filename))
printf '%s\n' "${tmp%,}" > filename
```

for the same effect.

Comment: Since we are assuming Bash: if "misbehave" refers to globbing, couldn't `set -f` be an effective fix?

Answer (score 0):

Method1:

```
perl -pe 's/\n/,/ unless eof' filename
```

output

```
8600,22007,93509,9984,22146
```

Method2(Using Python)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
m=open('file.txt','r')
j=[]
for i in m:
    j.append(i.strip())
print ",".join(j)
```

output

```
python i.py 
8600,22007,93509,9984,22146
```

Answer (score 0):

With awk:

```
awk '$1=$1' RS= OFS=, infile
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this transformation multiple ways, some of them being:

```
$ (head -n -1 - | tr \\n , ;cat -;) < inp

$ perl -lp -0777e 'chop;tr/\n/,/' inp

$ awk '$1=$1' FS="\n" RS= OFS=, inp

$ awk '{
     p = $0
    while ( getline > 0 ) p = p RS $0
     $0 = p
     gsub(/\n/, ",")
 }1' inp
```

POSIX-sed:

```
$ sed -e '
    :a
    ${s/\n/,/g;q;}
    N;ba
' inp
```

GNU-sed:

```
$ sed -e '
    $!{
        N
        s/^/\n/;D
    }
    y/\n/,/
'  inp


$ perl -0777 -pe 's/\n(?!\z)/,/g' inp

$ perl -lpe '$\ = eof ? $/ : ","' inp
```